# Return value related to file content header

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-2+

I have an attachment uploading feature in my web app.

File can have type- `image/png` or `image/jpg` or `image/jpeg` or `application/pdf`

For images, I need to return `Photo`, for pdf `Document`.

Documents will be only `pdf`, but images can be extended to `images/ico`, etc.

Now my code looks like this.

```
getAttachmentType(attachmentTypeHeader: string): string {
    if (
        attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/png' ||
        attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/jpg' ||
        attachmentTypeHeader === 'image/jpeg'
    ) {
        return 'Photo';
    }
    if (attachmentTypeHeader === 'application/pdf') {
        return 'Document';
    }
}
```

How I can make it check like `image/*`?

Comment: if (attachmentTypeHeader.startsWith('image/'))

Answer (score 2):

Usually if I have a big list of mappings from one `string` to another, that is *likely* to be later enhanced on, I use a *generic* mapping method, that is fed a *static* mapping constant.

So the first iteration would be something like:

```js
type ExpectedMimeTypes =
  'image/png' |
  'image/jpg' |
  'image/jpeg' |
  'application/pdf' |
  never;

type ExpectedMagicOutput =
  'Photo' |
  'Document' |
  'Unknown' |
  never;

type MimeTypeMapping = {
  [key in ExpectedMimeTypes]?: ExpectedMagicOutput 
}

const MAP_MIME_TYPE_TO_MAGIC_STRING: MimeTypeMapping = {
  'image/png': 'Photo',
  'image/jpg': 'Photo',
  'image/jpeg': 'Photo',
  'application/pdf': 'Document'
}

function getAttachmentType(attachmentTypeHeader: ExpectedMimeTypes): ExpectedMagicOutput {
  if (attachmentTypeHeader in MAP_MIME_TYPE_TO_MAGIC_STRING) {
    return MAP_MIME_TYPE_TO_MAGIC_STRING[attachmentTypeHeader]!; 
  } else {
    return 'Unknown';
  } 
}
```

If you are using TypeScript, go *all in*, meaning be *as specific as possible*. You do not expect *arbitrary* `string` as a result from `getAttachmentType()` but *specific* ones. You should explicitly model them, either by using *unions* or *string-based* enums. This fosters *reusability*.

The above solution gives you full type-safety, while being easily enhanced for other types; simply add them to the ExpectedMimeTypes and then you can easily add them to the constant `MAP_MIME_TYPE_TO_MAGIC_STRING` and vice versa, you *cannot* add mappings there, that have not been mentioned in the types above.

You could make `ExpectedMimeTypes` configurable by putting them into a dedicated file and let that be generated via a config and a simple script. That way you get both - configurable mime types and static compile type safety.